# Upgrade instructions if using software mirroring from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, raid, mdadm

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS ... I think I'd like to jump to 18.04, but I'm not sure what (if anything) I need to do with my mdadm array(s) I have two RAID 10 devices... one is a 35 GB swap (md0) and the other is the 2 TB ext4 file system mounted at root (md1)

I don't see anything in the instructions. Any ideas where I can read up on such things?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a system at home that has both RAID 10s and a RAID 5 in it.  The upgrade went really smooth.  There is always a possibility that something may go wrong during an upgrade so it is always best to have a good backup before you perform the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I run a RAID 5 filesystem mounted at root (md1) since Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. The migration from 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with this type of setup seems currently safe. One can read, for instance:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/07/help-test-the-improved-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-server-installer

Several people build test systems in various configurations and actually test the release upgrade tools. It is always worth waiting and reading until the upgrade of similar setups is reported safe and bug-free.

In the past, I had LVM over RAID setups. I never had an issue with automatic upgrades of this kind of setup, but I never tried to upgrade quickly, usually waiting until the end of support, unless I needed some new feature.